# How to extract a single file from a cpio archive?

Tags: backup, archive, cpio

I have a cpio archive with lots of files and I need to extract only one file, not all. With `tar` I could just use `tar -xf archive.tar path/to/file`, but that does not work with `cpio`:

```
cpio -i < archive.cpio path/to/file
bash: path/to/file: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know how to extract just a single file from a `cpio` archive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the `-d` option to let `cpio` create the leading directories (`path/to`) if they don't exist:

```
cpio -id < archive.cpio path/to/file
```

Also, `bsdtar` (the regular `tar` on FreeBSD) knows how to extract cpio archives, whether compressed or not.

Comment: Make sure to OMIT the leading forward slash on the /path/to/file... I mean... path/to/file... or it will not work!
Also, you can include more than one file with spaces in between them, just in case you want to extract TWO files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consume the file right away in a pipe you can skip the `-d` and
add `--to--stdout`

here is an overkill example - checking the MD5SUM of an executable in an initramfs cpio

```
$ objdump -sj '.init.ramfs' ./usr/initramfs_data.o | \
    tail -n +5 | \
    cut -b1-44 | \
    xxd -r | \
    gunzip | \
    cpio --to-stdout -i usr/bin/mount 2>/dev/null | \
    md5sum 
bffe60496ce15be471e7cfc04c14fac5  -
```

- the `tail` kills the lines before the hexdump from `objdump`
- The `cut` removes the ASCII porion of the hexdump
- `xxd -r` un-hexdumps (hex back to binary)